# Markov transition matrix for given problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on the following problem (in an introductory linear algebra course):

Every decade 15% of people in rural areas move into urban areas, and 5% of urban dwellers move into rural areas. What would be the eventual steady-state population distribution?

I came up with:

$U_{m+1}=.15R_m+.95U_m$

$R_{m+1}=.85R_m+.05U_m$

So

`| 0.15   0.95 | $R_m$
| 0.85   0.05 | $U_m$`

Now, my book uses

`| 0.85 0.05 | $U_m$
| 0.15 0.95 | $R_m$`

If I carefully check through my calculations, I find that their setup gives the right answer (steady state of 1/4, 3/4) and mine gives nothing of the sort. My question is: is my transition matrix just as valid as their matrix? If so, could someone demonstrate how to arrive at the correct answer with my transition matrix?

For eigenvalue of 1, their matrix gives:

`| -.15 0.05 |
| 0.15 -0.05 |`

Which you can see immediately leads to

`| -3 1 |
| 0 0 |`

Whereas  mine gives

`|-.85 .95 |
|.85 -.95 |`

Which leads to

`| 1 -1.117647 |
| 0 0 |`

Comment: It appears that you have a typo in your definition of $U_{m+1}$; it should be $0.15R_m + 0.95U_m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transition matrix doesn't work because you are switching the order of the basis vectors in the domain and the range. You have a map from a vector space to itself, so the most natural way to represent such a map is by using a single (ordered) basis for both the domain and the range of the map. In particular, if you want to iterate a map by exponentiating the matrix, then you are using the output of one application of the matrix as the input for the next iteration of the matrix, so the input and output had better be in the same basis.

Your matrix takes $(R_m,U_m)$ and returns $(U_{m+1},R_{m+1})$, switching the order, so your domain and range are being represented in different ordered bases.